# BindingResult não está trabalhando corretamente com o Validation

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, validator

Meu objetivo é cadastrar uma pessoa maior de idade e com nome valido, através do validation.

A classe `Person.java`:

```java
package br.com.Test.domain;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Person {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min= 2, max = 20, message="O Tamanho deve ser entre 2 a 20 caracteres")
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z]+$", message="Aceita só letras")
    private String name;

    @Min(value=18, message = "Tem que ser maior de idade")
    @Max(value = 150, message = "Digite uma idade valida")
    private int age;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



}
```

O `formulario.jsp` mostra a página do formulário para cadastrar a pessoa.

`formulario.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="adcionar" method="post" modelAttribute="person">
        Nome:<input type="text" name="name"/></br>
        Idade:<input type="number" name="age"/></br>
        <input type="submit" value="cadastrar"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

assim que o cadastro é feito, o sistema acessa o controller `MainControl.java`, onde ele verifica se os dados sobre o nome e a idade da pessoa estão válidos, se sim, ele acessa uma página para notificar de que os dados sobre as pessoas foram salvos, caso contrário ele volta pra página do formulário:

`MainControl.java`

```java
package br.com.Test.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import br.com.Test.domain.Person;

@Controller
public class MainControl {

    @RequestMapping("/formulario")
    public ModelAndView formulario()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("pessoa/formulario");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/adcionar")
    public ModelAndView adcionar(@Valid Person p, BindingResult br) {
        System.out.println("oi");
        if(br.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            return new ModelAndView("pessoa/formulario");
        }
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        System.out.println(p.getAge());
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("pessoa/adcionada");
        mav.addObject("pessoa",p);
        return mav;
    }

}
```

O problema: O binding result está cadastrando dados inválidos.

Ex: Cadastra usuário sem nome (""), cadastra usuário com nome inválido ("Luc45"), cadastra usuário menor de idade(<18). Nesses casos o `BindingResult.hasErrors()` retorna como false e permite a aprovação desses dados. O único caso que `BindingResult.hasErrors()` retorna como `True`, é quando eu cadastro a pessoa com o campo da idade em branco, ele consegue detecta o error, pq não pode cadastrar "" como idade, por ser uma `String`.

Gostaria de saber o que está faltando para o `BindingResult` trabalhar junto com `validation`, para reconhecer as outras invalidez?

`pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

<properties>
    <spring.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Alpha6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro explicitar o `Validator` a ser utilizado ao Spring:

1) Utilizando XML

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

2) Utilizando `@Configuration`

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfig {
    @Bean
    public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }   
}
```

Mais detalhes na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation)